# Can a sorc 19 / cleric 1 cast cleric spells at higher sorcerer levels?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, multi-classing, sorcerer

Inspired by [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/46442/3799)

> Sorc 19/Cleric 1 has a bit more issues. You only have the few L1 cleric spells, and lots of Sorcerer spells, make sure you took cleric spells that scale (so you can cast them in your higher level spell slots).

It is my understanding of 5E multiclassing that you can't cross over the spell lists from one class into the other. Am I mixed up? Is there something in either the cleric or sorcerer classes that allows this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are able to cast the cleric spells at a higher level.

While spells known / prepared are handled on a class basis, your spell slots are combined.

**PHB, page 164, Multiclassing, Spellcasting, Spell slots**

> Spell Slots. You determine your available spell slots 
>   by adding together all your levels ... Use this total to determine your spell slots by consulting the Multiclass Spellcaster table.

Regarding your ability to use the cleric spells in these slots, a few sentences later it says

> If a lower-level spell that you cast, like burning hands, has an 
>   enhanced effect when cast using a higher-level slot, you 
>   can use the enhanced effect.

Consult the multiclass spell slot table on the next page, and those are your slots. You can use any of the spells you have prepared, from either class, in any of those slots.

So, for example, as Sorcerer 19 / Cleric 1 you could cast Cure Wounds in your sole 9th level spot, healing for 9d8 + Wis, but then you would no longer be able to use that slot for sorcerer spells.

Comment: That's quite a neat way to fix the main issue that spellcasters had in multi-classing (compared to melee classes for which BAB stack).

Comment: Except 9d8 + Wis is terrible for a 9th level slot, when the sorc could be doing 40d6 damage over a huge area with Meteor Swarm. My general point is that some of these scalings seem trivial, as any spell of that slot has more power baked in already. Eg., casting MM using a 3rd level slot would deal 5d4+5 damage--about half of Fireball (8d6). I hope I'm missing something, as I really want to like 5E =P, but some of the caster changes don't seem to make much sense.