# Land Druid/Cleric Multiclass interaction with spells

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, druid, cleric, multi-classing

I have a Cleric 1/Druid X character and I want to make sure I'm using the multiclass rules for their spells correctly. As I've been leveling up, I've been preparing higher level cleric spells, even though I'm a level 1 cleric. Here's how I've been interpreting RAW:

At Level 1, I get the cleric's Spellcasting feature. It states:

> You prepare the list of cleric spells that are available for you to cast, choosing from the cleric spell list. When you do so, choose a number of cleric spells equal to your Wisdom modifier + your cleric level (minimum of one spell). The spells must be of a level for which you have spell slots.

The Multiclassing rules state to treat each class *individually* when preparing spells. But the rule doesn't state whether or not those spell slots have to come from the same class. Furthermore, both classes already have all the spells they can know available to them *and* can change them at the end of a long rest.

I think the biggest problem is that since both classes have the same spellcasting  ability and both have access to all spells available to their class, just not the spell slots, is what's making this interaction confusing for me. So, can I continue to prepare higher level Cleric spells despite being only a Level 1 Cleric?

Comment: Very related: [Can a sorc 19 / cleric 1 cast cleric spells at higher sorcerer levels?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46478/can-a-sorc-19-cleric-1-cast-cleric-spells-at-higher-sorcerer-levels), [Can a multiclass Wizard use any Wizard spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50424/can-a-multiclass-wizard-use-any-wizard-spell)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, it is quite clear in the text you quoted:

> You prepare the list of **cleric spells** that are available for you to cast, choosing from the **cleric spell list**.

This means that when choosing what spells to prepare at the end of a long rest, your cleric spells count against cleric spells prepared, and you must choose them from the cleric spell list.

Also, you may only prepare cleric spells at the rate you'd get them as a single-class cleric.  You can't prepare higher-level cleric spells, even if you have a higher-level spell slot to cast it in.  It's what the multiclass section says, but [here is Jeremy Crawford confirming that](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/941083631388213248):

> Multiclass spellcasting. You determine the spells you know/prepare for each class individually, pretending you have just that class. The slots you get from the multiclassing rules don't apply. You have 1 level in cleric? You prepare cleric spells as a 1st-level cleric.

On the bright side, you are able to upcast your lower-level prepared spells using the higher-level spell slot.